# How Can I Pull An Entire Result From A Foreach Loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to get the result from a foreach loop, but use it outside of the foreach brackets. What is the easiest way to do this.

Currently the below is working fine:

```
foreach($esmc->find('p') as $paragraph){
$showparag = $paragraph->innertext. '<br/>';
echo $showparag;//Will show result of array
}
```

However, I would like to have this so I can add text to it (echo is outside of foreach brackets):

```
foreach($esmc->find('p') as $paragraph){
$showparag = $paragraph->innertext. '<br/>';
}
echo "This shows results of array as $showparag";//Contains text + array
```

Currently if I do the second example, it is only returning the final record in the array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = 'This shows results of array as ';
foreach($esmc->find('p') as $paragraph){
    $showparag = $paragraph->innertext. '<br/>';
    $string .= $showparag;
}
echo $string;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

P.S. Despite there is a lot examples of global variables usage in the manual, you actually should not use it as it is considered as a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is rather vague, if this isn't what you want, can you please clarify in the comments.

This, however should generate a string for you to print all of the results as one string, outside of the foreach loop.

```
$showparag
foreach($esmc->find('p') as $paragraph){
    $showparag .= $paragraph->innertext. '<br/>';
}
echo "This shows results of array as $showparag";//Contains text + array
```